# column-count not affecting table

Tags: css, multiple-columns, column-count

The `column-count` property doesn't affect the table.
HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count: 3;
}
td{
    border:2px #000 solid;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8rydn/

**Update:**

If `column-count` is not a good option to use on a `<table>`, is there a better way to move 3 `<tr>`s onto each line?

Comment: I don't think it should be used for tables. What's your goal here ?

Comment: @dystroy I want 3 columns of `<tr>`s.

Comment: You can get it to work in Chrome and Opera by setting the table to block, but not Firefox:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/2uqtomam

Comment: Did you ever find a suitable solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#cc)

> Column Count Applies to: non-replaced block-level elements (except table elements),
>   table cells, and inline-block elements

Answer (score -3):

Cumbersome, but it seems to work.

```
<div style="-moz-column-count: 3; -webkit-column-count: 3; column-count: 3}">
  <table><tr><td style="width: 150px">key</td><td>value</td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td style="width: 150px">key</td><td>value</td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td style="width: 150px">key</td><td>value</td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td style="width: 150px">key</td><td>value</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Comment: If I'm going to have multiple table elements, I would use span or div elements instead.